# Win 10 install failing with 0x80070570

Tags: windows-10, installation, operating-systems, m.2, nvme

Just putting together a new build and trying to install windows 10 but getting 3% into coping files and getting the message "Windows cannot install required files. The file may be corrupt or missing..." 0x80070570

I'm installing from a sata dvd drive and the primary boot drive is the 950 pro nvme m.2

The drive shows in the bios, is setup in the boot order, and shows up during windows setup. Windows creates 4 partitions (system, reserved, recovery, and primary). I select primary it gets 3% into the 2nd step of "Coping files" and throws this error.

I've tried burning a new disc from my win10 ISO also tried another dvd drive to install from.

Comment: You mean the driver shows in "BIOS", does that mean you have Legacy Mode/CPM/Compatabiity Mode enable or disabled?

Comment: @Ramhound I've tried both. With CMS disabled, I reboot, the PC beeps a few times, reboots and reverts the setting back to enabled.

Comment: In order for this to work you must determine the reason you cannot boot to a EFI enabled disk.  You will be unable to use your SSD if you don't figure it out.  Try and use Rufus to create the installation disk.